# How to apply Grade Rule Table to DXF?

Tags: svg, autocad, cad, dxf

I have a rule associated with dxf file, the fragment is following:

```
GRADE RULE TABLE: 11111
NUMBER OF SIZES: 2
SIZE LIST: M L
SAMPLE SIZE: M
RULE: DELTA 1
      0.000,      -0.000
      100.000,      -0.000
RULE: DELTA 2
      0.000,      -0.000
      100.000,      -100.000
```

dxf file content like **# 1**、 **# 2** is associated with the grade rule table file, the point before **#**  is key points (which control the pattern shape), and there are many polygon vertex in the dxf file, **so how to connect polygon vertex and key points ,what is the relationship between polygon and key points ?** , the dxf fragment(include # 1) is following:

```
0
POINT
8
2
10
2551.112500
20
90.030000
0
TEXT
8
2
10
2551.112500
20
90.030000
40
5.000000
50
0.000000
1
# 1
7
STANDARD
0
POINT
8
2
10
2651.112500
20
-425.967500
```

Comment: It's not so easy. Looks like AAMA Standard. 
In pure DXF You may use points, polylines, blocks, regions, text and so one.
I met the standard looking simmilar to this which You mentioned, where we were talking about seam lines, cut lines, notches, holes and so one in textile branch.
There is no relationship between them in DXF. It's rather like description how to use DXF to describe textile items, like one tier above DXF.

Comment: hello, could you give some suggestions?

Comment: oh .....  is that other case than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767514/what-is-the-relationship-between-polylines-vertex-and-points-in-the-block-of-dxf/58817819?noredirect=1#comment104083750_58817819 ?
Or just duplicated question