# What is the relationship between polyLines vertex and points in the block of DXF file?

Tags: autodesk, cad, dxf

What is the relationship between polyLines and points in the block  of  DXF file? If I provide grade rule table file, how to connect them ?

[image: relationship ?]

[image: how to stretch the blue/green points]

Another question , too less scaled point, so it works not good, as the following image shows . as the first answer method, if the scaled point is too less, do we need generate the new scaled point which is on the arc which is formed by two known scaled point?

[image: too less scaled point，two scaled point on the right arc, so it works not good]

Comment: A block (insert) has an origin. The coordinates of points and polylines are all relative to that block origin.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Thanks for your answer. Could you describe clearly ? When I analyze the dxf file ,  how to connect grade rule table file to the dxf ?    Detail question description : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58765788/how-to-apply-grade-rule-table-to-dxf    . Please help me  or provide the example of url

Comment: I am afraid I don't have this level of knowledge. I have written routines designed to work with creating folds and creases for cardboard cutouts but not these grade rules. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such relationship.

In DXF format. block may contain different entities like points, lines, polylines. 
Each of them has:

- position for: point, text, block reference, attribute
- start point and endpoint in case of line
- coordinates for polylines

In grade rule table You have named points 
like point `#1, #2, #3`.

In AAMA DXF file there are text entities with content for example `#1`. You may have a lot of such texts in one DXF file, and one block.

For example RUL file ( Grade rule table) describes

- In Size S  point #1 has displacements X= -5 , Y= -3
- In Size M  point #1 has displacements X=  0 , Y=  0
- In Size L  point #1 has displacements X=  5 , Y=  3
- In Size XL point #1 has displacements X= 10 , Y=  6

Now in DXF file You have a block for example "Cuff size S". Inside this block You have a lot of lines, polylines.... on each coordinate of each entity You have Text ( or MText) on specific layer ( layer is "1" if I understand it correctly but it's described in standard ).

For example if on startline of polyline there is text `#1` You have to stretch it `X=-5,Y=-3`.

Other block would be "Cuff size M" so for each entity where on point there is extra text #1 coordinate should be not stretched because for point `#1` on M size, `X=0, Y=0`.

Other block would be "Cuff size XL" so for each entity where on point there is extra text #1 coordinate should be stretched size, `X=10, Y=6` because for point `#1` on `M` .

calculation formula would be like:

```
X1-(X1-X2)*( lx / L)
```

Where:

- lx - is distance between #1 and point to stretch - measured by curve not stright distance between points
- L - is distance between #1 and #2 - measured by curve not stright distance between points

Comment: Thanks for your detail description. What I really want to know is : we know point #1 、point #2 should be stretched according to the RUL file, but how to deal with some points among them ? For example point #1 is the startline of polyline, point #2 is another point on the polyline, but how to deal with the points between them?

Comment: Do You really have points on polyline which are not described by #x ? in this case I suppose You should interpolate them.

Comment: Yes ,  It could no be interpolated.  So how to stretch the points which are not described by #x ?

Comment: why  "could no be ineterpolated"  ?

Comment: Because my dxf is just the points which are key point and some polylines、curve line and so on.  the image which I describe above is that red point is key point, Green point is the points locate in the polylines 、curve line and so on.  The grade rule file "DELTA 1 : offset x offset y" only stretch for the key points, so I do not know how to stretch the points which on the curve line、polylines ....

Comment: is there convenient way for me to contact with you? Please check the above image,  thank u. This question is very import to me. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: You have to calculate delta of each green point. 
for example: if deltaX #1 is -5.0 and deltaY is 3.0 and distance between that points along the curve is 7.0, and the green point which delta You calculate is in the middle between #1 and #2 deltaX of point is -2.5 and deltaY is 1.5 . If the point is in distance from #1 is 2.0, than deltaX = (2.0/7.0)*-5.0 = -1.4285, deltaY=(2.0/7.0)*3=0.85714

Comment: Sorry, I can not understand clearly. Could you provide the image which flag the important point? what do you mean by points along the curve is 7.0 ? Do you mean calculate the distance from close points each other and sum up all distances on the curve lines ?

Comment: And you did not provide deltaX #2 and deltaY #2,  why does it not need  ？ And distance between that points along the curve is 7.0,  does it mean calculate the distance of  points along the curve ?

Comment: yes 7.0 is distance between poitns along the curve. 
deltaX #2 also is important.
I do it in this way: first stretch points between #1 and #2 based on delta #1, than stretch points between #2 and1 #1 based on delta #2 but I'm sure You can do in in one iteration by join delta #1 and #2.

Comment: the green point which delta You calculate is in the middle between #1 and #2 deltaX of point is -2.5 and deltaY is 1.5 ？I  think the middle deltaX = (deltaX #1 + deltaX #2) /2 , middle deltaY =  (deltaY #1 + deltaY #2) /2, we should take delta #2 in consideration.

Comment: yes, You are right. I'm working on sample for You, but working also on other task now, so it take some time

Comment: so current green point on the curve line, its deltaX = 2 / 7 *(deltaX #1 + deltaX #2)  , deltaY = 2/7 *(deltaY #1 + deltaY #2)   , 7 is distance between points along the curve, 2 is distance between #1 and the current point along the curve ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202383/discussion-between-cad-developer-and-jim-green).

Comment: @JimGreen the answer is edited by add formula. I think now the question is anwered.

Comment: As the formula and the sample image what you provided : ```X1-(X1-X2)*( lx / L) ```, x1 means the offset of #1 (27) , x2 means the offset of #2 (2.4 ), so the result value is  ```27 - (27-2.4) *(25.07 /125.0336) = 22.06754984 ``` ,   not 22.05 what you mean the correct answer, is  it  right?

Comment: as your method, if the scaled point is too less, do we need generate the new scaled point which is in the arc which is formed by two known scaled point?

Comment: I update the question above, Another question , too less scaled point, so it works not good. 
as your method, if the scaled point is too less, do we need generate the new scaled point which is in the arc which is formed by two known scaled point?

Comment: hello， as the formula，on the curve if the scaled point  is less， and the distance is long,  it may works not well,  see the third pic above?